# Windows unable to perform start-up repair

Tags: windows

I am not sure If I am putting this in the right place, but my desktop wont boot. I tried every mode option available and then I tried to do a start-up repair but It failed. It gave me a list of Problem Signatures, but I don't know what they mean. Could someone possibly explain what could be wrong and how I can maybe fix it?

Problem Event Name: StartupRepairOffline
Problem Signature 01: 6.1.7600.16385
Problem Signature 02: 6.1.7600.16385
Problem Signature 03: unknown
Problem Signature 04: 21200986
Problem Signature 05: AutoFailover
Problem Signature 06: 14
Problem Signature 07: NoRootCause

Comment: by "every mode option available" do you mean all the "Safe Modes"? And what operating system are you running? XP? Vista? Win7? Other?

Comment: What did you do before this occurred? I mean: hardware modifications, software installed, working during a thunderstorm (in 99.99% of the cases the worst you can get is a barbecue PSU but one never knows...).

Comment: Try to repair from a windows installation disk.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a spare PC, a friend willing to give you their PC, or you know where a cafe PC is, and you have a USB or an SD card with over 4GB, you can repair your system using **Ubuntu Linux.** If you don't know what Ubuntu is, go to [the official site](https://ubuntu.com). Your computer should be using Windows XP, Vista/7 or 8/8.1

1. Download an Ubuntu live ISO [here](https://ubuntu.com/download/desktop). As of 2021 January to March, Ubuntu 20.04 LTS is recommended, but you can also use 20.10 if you prefer. Check if you have 64bit or 32bit. I suppose you are using a 64bit PC.
2. Flash to a USB or SD card using software like [Rufus](http://rufus.ie) or [Etcher](http://etcher.io). The drive **MUST** be atleast 4GB.

2.5. Put the drive into the target system, in this case, your PC which needs to be fixed.

3. Boot into the live system by following these steps:

3.1. After the flash, reboot.

3.2. Press the boot manager key as soon as the boot logo appears. *This key is different on different computers depending on the manufacturer. For example, HP uses the F9 key, when Dell uses F12.*

3.3. Choose your drive. It may be listed as something like **SanDisk**.

**As soon as you boot into Ubuntu, you can NOT remove the drive.**

An error may appear saying *error: file /boot not found.* You can ignore this because if will only display for a split second.

After this, a menu will appear. This menu is called **GRUB** and will help to boot Ubuntu. Find more [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/).

4. If there is an option called **"Try Ubuntu without installing"**, navigate to it using the Up and Down keys, and select it using Enter. GRUB does not use the mouse. If there is only an option called Ubuntu, select it.

You will boot into the Ubuntu desktop, unless GRUB showed the Ubuntu option instead of the Try option. Then, you will need to click the option **Try Ubuntu**.

5. Open a terminal using Ctrl + Alt+ T. This is where we will get to fixing Windows.
6. Put this into the terminal:

   ```
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair

   sudo apt update

   sudo apt install boot-loader
   ```
7. This will install the **Boot Repair** application. To use it, click the 9 dots menu at the lower-left corner and search for the tool.

*Long note: This will be different if you installed a version UNDER 18.04 up to 20.10. (as of 2021 Jan - Mar) If you chose Ubuntu 16.04 and under, click the Ubuntu logo at the upper left. If you got an EVEN OLDER version under 11.04, click the Applications menu.*

A window will open.

8. Click *Recommended repair*. This may take time, so get something to do.
9. Reboot into Windows.
10. You should be greeted by the login screen.